# d3 tree graph - limiting zoom, panning

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, treemap

I have d3v4 treemap. I should be able to zoom and pan the tree, with pan/zoom limit.

Zoom and pan effects are working well. For limitation, `zooming` is limited by using `scaleExtent`.

```
svg.call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', () => {
  g.attr('transform', d3.event.transform)
})
.scaleExtent([0.5, 3]));
```

But this code has no impact on limitting the panning, panning refers to the dragging of treemap.

`height` and `width` are calculated dynamically based on the number of nodes.

```
this.svg.call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', () => {
        const scale = d3.event.scale;
        d3.event.transform.y = (height / 2);
        d3.event.transform.x = Math.min(d3.event.transform.x, 5);
        d3.event.transform.x = Math.max(d3.event.transform.x, (1 - d3.event.transform.k) * width );

        
        // I have tried this but couldn't able to drag backwards
        this.wrapperG.attr("transform", d3.event.transform.toString().replace(/scale\((.*?)\)/) + "scale(" + scale + ")");
        })
        .scaleExtent([0.5, 3]));
```

Would like to hear suggestions to make this work

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try `translateExtent`? https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_translateExtent

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yes I tried like this `.translateExtent([[-width , -height], [width, height]])`, but when zooming in and zooming out it's not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

To limit the pan, you can use:

```
svg.call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', () => {
  g.attr('transform', d3.event.transform)
})
.scaleExtent([0.5, 3])
.translateExtent([[0,0],[width,height]])); // limit pan to original SVG dimensions
```

In the example code above, you have to set value to `x0` and `y0`, where it appears  `[0,0]` here

More reference, check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51092399/map-zoom-and-pan-in-d3-js-v4-scale-limit)